# Substring: Starting index out of range with big-bang

Tags: racket

"Pictured Programs" [http://www.facom.ufu.br/~marcelo/PF/pictures_racket.pdf](http://www.facom.ufu.br/%7Emarcelo/PF/pictures_racket.pdf) is the book I'm working out of and Ch.10. I'm trying to use what has been introduced in the book in a linear fashion. The program is suppose to cut the first character off of the string when a mouse moves or clicks which it does, but I can't find a way to stop it from throwing the out of range [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I18J1.png).

I've tried several different approaches and spent hours on it unfortunately. This must be done **without** conditionals, loops, built-in functions not mentioned yet, & etc...

Any tips would be appreciated.

Here is the actual [Exercise questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfS3R.png).

```
(require picturing-programs)

(define (add-str s)
  (string-append  s "b"))

(define (a-with-b s)
   (text s 18 "green"))

(define (chop-first-on-mouse s mouse-x mouse-y me)
  (substring s 1 (string-length s)))

(define (string-world s)
  (big-bang s
    (check-with string?)
    (on-tick add-str 1/2)
    (on-draw a-with-b 200 200)
    (on-mouse chop-first-on-mouse)))

(string-world  "a")
```

Comment: If you chop off one character on every mouse-moved event, the string is going to become empty very quickly. Check whether it is empty first, or make sure it never is.

Comment: You don't need conditionals to write conditional things. Check out the values of `(or (and #f "false") "else")` and `(or (and #t "true") "else")`.

Comment: Okay I get it that you can solve these with conditionals, but I'm trying to solve these exercises without approaches that have not been mentioned in the book yet. Thanks for the help though @molbdnilo

Comment: Those are not conditionals, they are logical operators. (And you haven't said what's been mentioned in the book. You haven't even said what the book is.)

Comment: http://www.facom.ufu.br/~marcelo/PF/pictures_racket.pdf "Pictured Programs" is the book I'm working out of and Ch.10. @molbdnilo Correct, but the logical operators have not been introduced yet. I have worked in HTDP and I have done more complicated exercises, but I'm trying to use what has been introduced in the book in a linear fashion.

Comment: But `min` was introduced in chapter 7, so cjeck out `(substring "" (min 1 (string-length "")))` and `(substring "abb" (min 1 (string-length "abb")))`.

Comment: @molbdnilo It looks like (substring s (min 1 (string-length s))) is producing the expected outcome. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to improve the program, there was one piece of code added to the function definition (chop-first-on-mouse ...), which was the built-in function (min). This was the only change that was needed to obtain the desired results.

This appears to give the desired output because the newly defined/refined call to "chop-first-on-mouse" now only deletes one char at a time and also does not throw an error(always stays within range of substring parameters).

While before the original call to "chop-first-on-mouse" would go out of range and it would also delete chars too quickly to analy 's/z' e.

```
(require picturing-programs)

(define (add-str s)
  (string-append  s "b"))

(define (a-with-b s)
   (text s 18 "green"))

# Only change to program is the built-in function (min) in the substring call below 
(define (chop-first-on-mouse s mouse-x mouse-y me)
  (substring s (min 1 (string-length s))))

(define (string-world s)
  (big-bang s
    (check-with string?)
    (on-tick add-str 1/2)
    (on-draw a-with-b 200 200)
    (on-mouse chop-first-on-mouse)))

(string-world  "a" )
```

Comment: To be a good answer here on SO you need to explain what the chnages were and why they are an improvement.